# Type from right to left

Tags: vim, right-to-left

Is there a command to make Vim type from right to left? If not us any one aware of this plugin?

Comment: Are you talking about in the context of a right-to-left language such as Arabic of Farsi, or do you just want to advance the cursor to the left when inputting normal western alphabet characters? Please edit your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Sure!

```
:set rightleft
```

Or, just `:set rl`. However, this will save the file with the characters in the order you typed them in. If you want to have it save it reversed, type `:%!rev` before saving.

If you use `:set revins` (`:set ri` for short), the inserting is done backwards. You could probably map this to a key combination, but that's up to you.

Here is the appropriate section of Vim help:

> ### Typing backwards *[ins-reverse](https://vimhelp.org/rileft.txt.html#ins-reverse)*
>
> ---
>
> In lieu of using full-fledged the
> ['rightleft'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27rightleft%27) option, one can opt for
> reverse insertion.  When the
> ['revins'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27revins%27) (reverse insert) option is set,
> inserting happens backwards. This can be used to type right-to-left
> text. When inserting characters the cursor is not moved and the text
> moves rightwards. A  deletes the character under the cursor.
> CTRL-W and CTRL-U also work in the opposite direction.  , CTRL-W
> and CTRL-U do not stop at the start of insert or end of line, no matter
> how the ['backspace'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27backspace%27) option is set.
>
> There is no reverse replace mode (yet).
>
> If the ['showmode'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27showmode%27) option is set, "-- REVERSE INSERT --" will be shown
> in the status line when reverse Insert mode is active.

Comment: Was not the effect I was looking for but definitely the right answer to the question I asked. I am actually working in a left to right file. Sometimes I like to define my statements backwards is there a way to just type a few characters right to left with out changing the flow of the document?

Comment: Ty for the update to that I had missed it. I appreciate it.