# How to type a right to left language in terminal?

Tags: debian, command-line, nano, right-to-left

I have installed **Debian** recently (without a GUI) to learn the [CLI](http://cli.learncodethehardway.org/book/) and [C](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/) using the [LearnCodeTheHardWay](http://learncodethehardway.org/) tutorials. Its going well, and I feel at this stage I do not need any GUI.

However, one thing I might need is to view, and edit in a right to left language, specifically Arabic using say... nano. Or with sqlite. Is that possible?

**EDIT:**
`VIM` or `EMACS` will be fine also. I do not mind the text editor. Also I would like to do this without install X, or any GUI stuff of any sort.

**EDIT:**
By `Terminal` what I understand is the black window with the $ symbol, which is what you get with the default Debian install. Its using Bash, and I use SSH to remote into it.

Comment: The `nano` editor is by definition minimalistic so I would be really surprised if you could configure it this way. The only editors I'm aware of that can display and edit text from right to left are `emacs` and `vim`.

Comment: By “terminal”, do you mean the Linux console (i.e. outside X)? I don't think it supports right-to-left. It's an interface to repair the system, not for doing regular work. An editor such as Vim or Emacs should be able to cope, but the available Arabic fonts may be limited. X has advantages even if you only use it to run terminal emulators — and even Vim and Emacs are more comfortable in their own X window.

Comment: @Gilles any kind of support, even limited would be good. I am a windows user, so all I do is add a new keyboard (AR) and away I go typing... what would be the steps in debian do at least type an arabic character in vim or emacs?

Comment: @Gilles whatever gave you the idea that the console is not for doing regular work?

Answer (score 1):

see [comparison of text editors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors) , do an intersection between "right-to-left and bidirectional text" and "text shell integration" .

---

```
:set lefttoright
```

for vim . see [documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/rileft.html) and [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19377/type-from-right-to-left) .

--

emacs generally can autodetect language and do the corresponding layout , on a per paragraph basis . see [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Bidirectional-Edit) .

Comment: this won't fix right to left support through ssh. also @لَا إِلٰهَ إِلَّا الله is clearly asking for character support, and not switching the cursor to the right.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-en-base
sudo apt-get install language-pack-ar-base
sudo locale-gen en
sudo locale-gen ar
```

Then edit **(i used vim)** `/etc/default/locale` or `/etc/environment` to contain just the following

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8  
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Finally

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

These steps will give you arabic over an ssh terminal.

Comment: you don't say what editor programme you use .

Comment: updated the answer