# Vim: Reverse right to left

Tags: vim

I have accidently `:set rl` thinking it's for relative lines. I have activated [right to left mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19377/type-from-right-to-left). The [doc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/rileft.html) for `rightleft` doesn't say how to reverse `rl mode` without exiting vim.

How does one go left to right in vim?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```viml
:set norl
```

or

```viml
:set norightleft
```

Each boolean option in Vim has a corresponding `no`-option that turns it off.

---

The option you were originally looking for might have been `relativenumber` (`rnu`), which acts like `number` (`nu`) but adds line numbers that are relative to the *current* line rather than to the start of the editing buffer.

Comment: "Most (all?)" all the boolean options.

Comment: @JoL I wasn't 100% it was _all_ of them, so I didn't want to make a definite statement, and I'm still not entirely certain :-)

Comment: I haven't tried them all either, but the documentation for `:set` describes it as a generic syntax rather than some convention: `:se[t] no{option} Toggle option: Reset, switch it off.`. It also has other syntaxes like `:se[t] inv{option}`, `:se[t] {option}!`, and `:se[t] {option}?`.

Answer (score 4):

Turn options on or off with !

```
set rightleft!
```

---

To quote the Vim help:

```
                                                           *:set-!* *:set-inv*
:se[t] {option}!   or
:se[t] inv{option}      Toggle option: Invert value. {not in Vi}
```

You can see this in the built-in Vim help by typing `:help :set-!` from inside Vim.